# Finding the maximum value in a list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have some code which looks like this

```
public int getMobID()
{
    int maxMobID = 0;

    foreach (Farm f in subscription.Farms)
    {
        foreach (Paddock p in f.Paddocks)
        {
            foreach (AnimalMob m in p.Mobs)
            {
                if (m.AnimalMobID >= maxMobID)
                {
                    maxMobID = m.AnimalMobID + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxMobID;
}
```

which I'm thinking would probably be faster using LINQ but I'm unsure what it would look like and indeed if it can be done.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SelectMany to project them into one list, and then parallelize everything. Something like:

```
subscription.Farms.AsParallel().SelectMany(x => 
          (x.Paddocks.SelectMany(
              y => y.Mobs.Select(j => j.AnimalMobId))).Max();
```

Note that you could only POSSIBLY gain performance if you use this Parallel version. Otherwise LINQ will be definitely slower.

Comment: _"Otherwise LINQ will be definitely slower"_ this is not necessarily true and even if it might be micro-optimization to avoid LINQ because of a few milliseconds.

Comment: I hear you. Personally I would avoid LINQ in this case - doesn't feel justified to obstruct the code for beginners & lose a little control over the code(debugging) just to save 2 lines.

Comment: Works a treat - I'm trying to get as much as I can as the code must run on mobile devices, so every millisecond counts :)

Answer (score 4):

> which I'm thinking would probably be faster

LINQ is normally not *faster* but more *readable* since it also uses loops.

```
var animalMobIDs = from farm in subscription.Farms
                   from paddock in farm.Paddocks
                   from mob in paddock.Mobs
                   select mob.AnimalMobID;
int maxMobID = 0;
if(animalMobIDs.Any())
    maxMobID = animalMobIDs.Max() + 1;
```

By the way, this is the query version of `Enumerable.SelectMany` which i find more readable than the method syntax (same applies to `Enumerable.Join` imho).

Answer (score 3):

I think this LINQ query will be enough, both in term of performance and readability:

```
subscription.Farms.SelectMany(f => f.Paddocks)
                  .SelectMany(p => p.Mobs)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                  .Max(m => m.AnimalMobID + 1);
```

Comment: But OP wants to add +1 to the highest `AnimalMobID` (if there's is at least one).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, true, I've missed that. Fixed answer.

Comment: this code was the reason i finally switched to query syntax since it contradicted the argument that LINQ can be more readable ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's matter of preference, for me it is more readable that your query syntax ;)